# Cylindrical coordinates where $z$ axis is not axis of symmetry.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, volume

I'm a little bit uncertain of how to set up the limits of integration when the axis of symmetry of the region is not centered at $z$ (this is for cylindrical coordinates). The region is bounded by $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$. This is my attempt:

Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

We are bounded on $z$ by $\pm\sqrt{4-r^2}$. We take $0\leq r\leq 2\cos\theta$ and $-\pi/2\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$ to account for the fact that the cylinder is not centered with the $z$ axis (shift on the $x$ axis). The volume is given by
$$
V = \int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int\limits_0^{2\cos\theta}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} dz\,(r\,dr)\,d\theta \ .
$$

Comment: $$(x-1)^2+y^2=1\longrightarrow x^2-2x+1+y^2=1\longrightarrow x^2+y^2-2x=0\longrightarrow r^2-2r\cos\theta=0$$ so the range for $r$ would be $r|_{0}^{2\cos\theta}$. The range for $\theta$ looks fine and for $z$ you did it correct. So what is it your question exactly? :)

Comment: Mostly I am uncertain about the range of $r$ when the axis of symmetry is shifted. I have not seen how to get the limits for $r$ in this case and there were no similar problems or examples in my text. Then someone said my set up is incorrect, but I could not see what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect, the OP's solution is correct. The circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ sits inside the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, so the region in question projects onto the entire disk $\{(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1\}$. Thinking about $z$ cross-sections is awkward and to be discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Dr. Shifrin! Btw, I have been enjoying your multivariable text as a reference in my course! So double thanks!

Comment: With all due respect, sir, I find the cross sections easier to visualize.  The result below is not at all awkward in my opinion - beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  The results both agree.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to visualize the cross sections in $z$.  Draw a picture of various cross-sections in $z$: there is an intersection region for each $z$

[image: 3D Figure]

[image: Cross sections]

You have to find the points where the cross-sections intersect:

$$4-z^2=4 \cos^2{\theta} \implies \sin{\theta} = \pm \frac{z}{2} \ .$$

For $\theta \in [-\arcsin{(z/2)},\arcsin{(z/2)}]$, the cross-sectional area integral at $z$ looks like

$$\int_{-\arcsin{(z/2)}}^{\arcsin{(z/2)}} d\theta \: \int_0^\sqrt{4-z^2} dr \, r = (4 -z^2)\arcsin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) \ .$$

For $\theta \in [-\pi/2,-\arcsin{(z/2)}] \cup [\arcsin{(z/2)},\pi/2]$, this area is

$$2 \int_{\arcsin{(z/2)}}^{\pi/2} d\theta \: \int_0^{2 \cos{\theta}} dr \, r  = \pi - 2 \arcsin\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) -z \sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{4}} \ . $$

To get the volume, add the above two expressions and integrate over $z \in [-2,2]$; the expression looks odd, but we are really dealing with $|z|$ :

$$V = 2 \int_{0}^2 \: \left(\pi + (2-z^2) \arcsin\left( \frac{z}{2}\right) -z \, \sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{4}}\right)\,dz = \frac{16 \pi}{3} - \frac{64}{9} \ .$$

Comment: Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Your welcome, I hope it provides a deeper understanding of what is going on.

Comment: It is an interesting approach and I appreciate seeing different ways of solving the same problem. I tried something similar before realizing that the upper $r$ limit is $r=2\cos\theta$, but this is much nicer than what I was attempting. I also tried shifting the cylinder so that its axis of symmetry was along $z$ (of course shifting the sphere appropriately). But this method did not work out as nicely.

Comment: The answer (volume) is actually $(16\pi/3)-(64/9)$, I believe.

Comment: @5space: yes, that's right; I wrote the wrong answer in.  Thanks.

Comment: @5space: Mr. Shifrin's opinion notwithstanding, it does make sense in many situations to consider cross-sections normal to an axis of symmetry, as is the case here.  They are easy to visualize, and while in this case it does require breaking up the area integral into 2 pieces, it is a minor inconvenience at worst as we recombine into a single expression.  The volume is then reduced to a single integral, which in this case has a closed form.  (It also helps me that I have loads of experience doing integrals over circular intersection regions.)

Comment: Well, if your goal is to reduce problems to single integration, then it's the way to go. As a small challenge, I'll throw out one of my favorite problems: Find the volume of the region bounded by the three cylinders $x^2+y^2=1$, $x^2+z^2=1$, and $y^2+z^2=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: here is a link to my answer to your problem.  http://stackexchange.moderatenerd.com/2013/04/21/volumes-of-three-cylinders/

Comment: I apologize: I didn't intend for my "favorite question" to end up with a posted solution. Your solution is correct, but there is seriously more symmetry of the region in $\mathbb R^3$ of which to take advantage!